# Analog of the memoryless property for Erlang distributions

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a random variable with Erlang distribution with discrete parameter equal to 2 (i.e., a gamma distribution with shape parameter 2), then the distribution of

$X-d|X > d$

is a two-point mixture of the same Erlang distribution with the Erlang distribution with shape parameter changed to 1 (so it's an exponential distribution).

This can be proved just by noting that the survival function of $X-d|X>d$ is

$s(x) = \frac{1-\Gamma(2,\frac{x+d}{d})}{1-\Gamma(2,1)} = e^{-x/d}(1+\frac{x}{2d})$

(using the incomplete gamma function) and comparing with the survival function of the stated two-point mixture.

I have three questions:

1. Does this property or its generalization to arbitrary Erlang distributions have a name?
2. Is there some way to think of this property intuitively, in terms of waiting times, or some version of pseudo-memorylessness, or ...?
3. How does this property generalize to Erlang distributions with arbitrary shape parameter?

(Edited to remove a claim that the two-point mixture had equal weights, per heropup's answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume all rate parameters are $1$ and assume all supports are on the interval $[0,\infty)$.  Let $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2,1)$ with PDF $$f_X(x) = x e^{-x}$$ and survival $$S_X(x) = (1+x)e^{-x}.$$  The conditional variable $Y(d) = X - d \mid X > d$ has survival $$\begin{align}
S_{Y(d)}(y) &= \Pr[X - d > y \mid X > d] \\
&= \frac{\Pr[X > y + d]}{\Pr[X > d]} \\
&= \frac{S_X(y+d)}{S_X(d)} \\
&= \frac{(1+y+d)e^{-(y+d)}}{(1+y)e^{-y}} \\
&= \left(1 + \frac{y}{1+d}\right)e^{-y}.
\end{align}$$
Hence the density of $Y(d)$ is
$$f_{Y(d)}(y) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+d}\right) e^{-y} + \frac{1}{1+d} ye^{-y}.$$
This is a mixture of $X$ with an exponential distribution but with mixing weight $1/(1+d)$, rather than equal weights, and this makes intuitive sense, because if $d = 0$, we would have $Y(0) = X - 0 \mid X > 0 = X$, which is Erlang; this property could not hold if $Y(d)$ were an mixture distribution with equal weights.

I don't know if this mixture property has a name.

The salient question in my mind is, does this property continue to hold in some fashion?  Specifically, if $Y(d)$ is the aforementioned mixture, will the the new conditional variable, say
$$Z(d,d') = Y(d) - d' \mid Y(d) > d'$$
also be some mixture of $X$ and an exponential distribution--i.e., will it have the same form as $Y(d)$?  Well,
$$S_{Z(d,d')}(z) = \frac{\Pr[Y(d) > z + d']}{\Pr[Y(d) > d']} = \frac{(1 + \frac{z+d'}{1+d})e^{-(z+d')}}{(1+\frac{d'}{1+d})e^{-d'}} = \left(1 + \frac{z}{1+d+d'}\right)e^{-z} = S_{Y(d+d')}(z),$$
so the answer to this question is yes:  the variable $Z(d,d')$ is a mixture with weight $1/(1+d+d')$ of an Erlang and an exponential distribution.

If we think of a homogeneous Poisson point process with intensity $1$, the interpretation of $X$ would be the time to observe the second of two successive events (rather than the next event).  Then the interpretation of $Y(d)$ is that given we have waited at least $d$ to observe the second of two successive events, the additional time it takes is distributed as the aforementioned mixture of an Erlang and exponential waiting time.  Intuitively, the longer we have waited without having seen the second event, the more likely it is that we have seen the first and are just waiting for the second, so the additional time distribution will be more like an exponential; conversely, if we have not waited very long, then it is more unlikely to have seen any events, thus the additional time to wait is more like the Erlang.  Of course, this is hardly a formal proof--it is just an interpretation of the reasonableness of the mixture result in terms of the Poisson process.

Note that we could also have directly reasoned that since $d, d' \ge 0$,
$$\begin{align}
Z(d,d') &= Y(d) - d' \mid Y(d) > d' \\
&= (X - d) - d' \mid (X - d > d' \mid X > d) \\
&= X - (d+d') \mid X > (d+d') \\
&= Y(d+d').
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very clear and answered all my questions. Thanks. I edited the original equation to remove the "equal-weights" statement and put a note about the editing at the end. I had been assuming that the d equaled the rate parameter. It is still maybe interesting to me that the exact moment at which the equal mixing occurs is when you reach the expected waiting time, but not surprising.